# Access a page host by hostinger via his IP address

Tags: c#, android, url, ip

For my mobile app, I have to access a page hosted on hostinger via its IP address. This page return datas from the database to my C# code (the app code). The C# works perfect with any IP address like google's but not with my page's one.
It is hosted on hostinger and when I try to access it on my browser, It put a 404 error.
Does anyone know why? Is it because of hostinger?

How can I access to this page via an url with IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if anyone is looking for it : if you want to access your website by IP address, you have to have a dedicated IP address. And with mutualized servers like hostinger, it is not possible. o2switch can.

Comment: I also have encountered this problem but o2switch is only in french. Is there an ENG translate?

Comment: No it's just french. But you can have other like OVH, I think. You just have to check for 'dedicated IP address" in the offer